# Can this be done with list comprehension or lambda?

Tags: python

I've been stuck on this for a while now, and can't figure out how I can transform this function into a one-liner. I'm aware it also may be done by a standard for-loop, but I don't want to do it that way.

```
def set_num_children(individs):
    avg_fitness = calc_avg_fitness(individs)
    def calculation(individ):
        individ[2] = round(individ[1]/avg_fitness)
        return individ

    return map(calculation, individs)
```

Comment: Where is `calc_avg_fitness()` defined?

Comment: what are the variable types?

Comment: Why are you using `map` with a mutative function?

Comment: @user2357112 Why is it wrong to use map here? I'm not really used to using map at all.

Comment: `map` carries a strong implication that the mapped function is side-effect-free. Sort of like how you wouldn't expect `print` to do anything but print, people usually wouldn't expect `map` to mutate its input. (It looks like both answerers may have entirely missed the fact that you're mutating the input; the answers aren't mutating the input, and they don't say anything about how this is different from what you're doing.)

Comment: @user2357112 Okay, I see. So I guess it would be correct to write "return [calculation(individ) for individ in individs]"?

Comment: @Panto: Why are you using a mutative function at all? And if you're going to mutate the input, why are you also building a new list? It's standard to either build a new list without modifying the original, or modify the original without returning it. ([Command-query separation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation)) (If you want to modify the original, the way to do that would be with a regular `for` loop, not map or a list comprehension.)

Comment: @user2357112 I don't know, I just find it hard to work with data analysis and nested lists without mutating data. I should probably learn Haskell or something.

Answer (score 1):

This is as close as it can get:

```
avg_fitness = calc_avg_fitness(individs)
[[x[0], x[1], round(x[1] / avg_fitness)] for x in individs]
```

Even though we *could* in-line the call to `calc_avg_fitness`, we shouldn't, it doesn't make sense to calculate it more than once... this is inefficient:

```
[[x[0], x[1], round(x[1] / calc_avg_fitness(individs))] for x in individs]
```

Either way, we return a list of "individs", which are three-element lists with the third being the required calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, `[(individ[0], individ[1], round(individ[1]/avg_fitness)) for individ in individs]` would be the literal translation. Maybe clean it up a bit though.

Comment: `calculation()` does not return the 2nd element

Comment: Also that assumes there wasn't more elements, or a variable number of elements, or whatnot. Too hard to tell from the example given.